# Buffer em base URI javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

Bom estou tentando salvar em meu banco `Mysql` uma coluna em `Blob`, no banco ele está salvando perfeitamente assim:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAXEAAACICAMAAAAmsyvzAAAAhFBMVEX///8cY7cAWLMAVrIAWrQAVbIXYbbu8vjI1usAXLQAU7ESX7bb5fL3+v3y9vvA0Ojf5/Pl7PbR3e64yuVmj8mxxeKmvN6Zs9ooarpUg8Ryl82GpdMxb7zM2eyMqdWuwuF7ndA+db9ciMZPgMNDecCVsNiCotKft9t2ms4ubbtsk8sAQKu1P
```

Porém quando estou fazendo o `get` em minha `API` está retornando do tipo `Buffer`, tentei utilizar algumas coisas que achei aqui no `stack` porém nenhum delas funcionou para mim. O retorno está como da imagem:

[image: banco de dados e retorno da api]

A função que tentei utilizar foi:

```
  arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    let binary = '';
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    let len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
  }
```

Meu modelo utilizando `nodejs` com `sequelize` eu fiz assim:

```
// Config
import ApiConfig from '../../config/api.conf';
import { BasicFields } from '../basicFields';

const seq = (sequelize, dataTypes) => {

    // Define environment object
    const basicFields = new BasicFields(dataTypes);
    const config = new ApiConfig();
    const environment = config.getEnv();

    const model = sequelize.define('logo', {
        id: {
            field: "id",
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            required: true
        },
        title: {
            field: 'title',
            type: dataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            required: false
        },
        base64: {
            field: 'base64',
            type: dataTypes.BLOB('tiny'),
            allowNull: false,
            required: true
        },
        situation: basicFields.setFieldSituation(),

    }, {
            tableName: 'logo',
            paranoid: true,
        }
    );

    return model;

};

module.exports = seq;
```

Diante disso tudo, preciso do retorno da mesma forma que está salva no banco, ou no `front` (preferencial) ou no `back` preciso fazer este parse para retornar a `string` contendo "data:image/...."

Comment: Já tentou usar ***new FileReader().readAsText(buffer)***? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Você pode salvar somente o base64 sem o "data:image/png;base64,". Feito isso você pode receber esse buffer do banco e converter para base64 e adicionar a tag depois. acho mais pratico. Você pode usar `.toString('base64')`.